# Estimate the error of two algebraic equations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

> Let $f, \tilde f$ be two continuous scaler functions from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f-\tilde f| \leq \epsilon$. Suppose that $f(x) = 0$ and $\tilde f(x) = 0$ has exactly two solutions. Let $x^*, \tilde x^*$ be the largest solution of $f$ and $\tilde f$, respectively. Can we give find the upper bound of $|x^*-\tilde x^*|$ in term of $\epsilon, f, \tilde f$? Does it imply that $|x^*-\tilde x^*| \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Update: As answer from Lutzl, we can not get the bound of $|x^*-\tilde x^*|$. My next question is what kind of assumptions do we need if I want to get the upper bound of $|x^*-\tilde x^*|$ in term of $\epsilon, f, \tilde f$? and what is the bound?

Comment: Do you have any additional information, fixed point schemes, derivatives information, metric regularity?

Comment: I don't have any further assumption. But I welcome the solution with some additional assumptions.

Comment: @LutzL (to LutzL only) I realize that you live in BL.  I am studying at FU Berlin now :))

Comment: If $\inf_x |f'(x)|>c$, $\inf_x |\tilde f'(x)|>c$ then both functions are continuously invertible and the function values relate to the distance to the root set. However, it is non-trivial to get two roots per function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}$ and $f(x)=\frac{ϵ}3\phi(x-a)$ and $\tilde f(x)=\frac{ϵ}3\phi(x-b)$. Then all assumptions are satisfied, however no control over the values $a,b$ and thus the roots at $a+1, b+1$ can be obtained.

---

One strategy to lead to a positive result is to have some growth condition on $f$ so that you can localize points $x_\pm$ with $\pm f(x_\pm)\ge 2ϵ$ ( or some other value $>ϵ$). Then $\pm\tilde f(x_\pm)>0$ so that $\tilde f$ has a root via the intermediate value theorem between $x_-$ and $x_+$, leading to $|x^*-\tilde x^*|\le|x_+-x_-|$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What kind of assumptions do I need if I want to give the bound of $x^* - \tilde x^*$ in term of $f, \tilde f, \epsilon$?